# How to remove Gravatar Message from Buddypress Profile

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress, gravatar

I want to remove/hide

> "Your profile photo will be used on your profile and throughout the
>   site. If there is a Gravatar associated with your account email we
>   will use that, or you can upload an image from your computer."

message from BuddyPress Profile Photo upload section.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto:  **src/public_html/wp-content/themes/(Theme Name)/buddypress/members/single/profile/change-avatar.php** and remove the following coding. May be 25 to 29 lines

```
<figure class="callout-blockquote light">
    <blockquote>
        <p><?php _e( 'Your profile photo will be used on your profile and throughout the site. If there is a <a href="http://gravatar.com">Gravatar</a> associated with your account email we will use that, or you can upload an image from your computer.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>
    </blockquote>
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<p><?php _e( 'Your avatar will be used on your profile and throughout the site. If there is a <a href="http://gravatar.com">Gravatar</a> associated with your account email we will use that, or you can upload an image from your computer.', 'buddypress'); ?></p>
```

located in buddypress\bp-themes\bp-default\members\single\profile\change-avatar.php